# Htaccess: redirect some pages from one domen to another

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect some pages from one domen to another. Example:
`example.com/help/questions(/show/some_text|none|get params)` to `example2.com/questions(/show/some_text|none|get params)`

htaccess:

```
Redirect permanent /help/questions    http://example2.com/questions
```

But redirect from `example.com/help/questions/show/some_text` doesn't work - I have `example2.com/help/questions/show/some_text` instead `example2.com/questions/show/some_text`
With such code I have some problem.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com/help/questions
RewriteRule (.*) http://example2.com/questions/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How I can fix it?
All another pages redirect normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches host name not URI.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^help/(questions/.*) http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: I am still have such problem: But redirect from `example.com/help/questions/show/some_text` doesn't work - I have `example2.com/help/questions/show/some_text` instead `example2.com/questions/show/some_text`. `help` is not necessary

Comment: Make sure to keep this rule as your first rule and completely clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have set "AllowOverride All" in httpd.conf or apache.conf.
2. Make sure you have rewrite_module, headers_module, and alias_module apache modules enabled.